# Which wavelengths is limestone most transparent to?

Tags: geophysics, soil, limestone, radar

I think of the non-ionizing range, e.g. Terahertz or Radio. Limestone clearly is transparent to x-ray or gamma but thats not what i am asking for. Natural to low ranges of porosity/water content assumed.

Comment: What are you trying to do?